Exhaust fan electrical problem
I am installing an exhaust fan and I have a 1 black and 1 white and a ground. The fan has five wires. Two black each labeled fan and light and two white each labeled fan and light. How do I connect these?

Do you have a wall switch controlling the fan/light or just the black/white power?  Do you want the fan and light to always be on/off together?

Didn't the fan come with some type of instruction sheet?

You have two options:

Single Switch

This is super-easy. All blacks together. All whites together. All grounds together. One switch (on the other end of the black wire, with the white wire next to it but not actually connected to the switch) controls fan and light at the same time. Advantage: super easy. Disadvantage: No separate controls and no upgrade path.

Two Switches

First you need to run a new 2-wire (plus ground) cable for a 2nd switch, or replace the existing 2-wire cable with a 3-wire (plus ground) cable.
Then you connect incoming hot of the old and new switches together. If you are replacing the 2-wire with a 3-wire then disconnect the old switched hot (black)/neutral (white) and connect the new black and white in their place and red to the new switch. If you are adding a second 2-wire cable then add the new white to the existing group of white wires and connect the new black wire to the new switch.
Advantage: Separate control now, future possible upgrade to dim light and/or speed control of fan by replacing ordinary switches. Disadvantage: A lot more work.
